# Bind Data in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I am using Reactjs for my project. I have some problem about removing data in child component and notice the change in randparent component . Here is the code for grandparent component:`

```
class GrandParent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuData: [
        { menu: "1", optionName: "A" },
        { menu: "2", optionName: "A" },
        { menu: "3", optionName: "B" },
        { menu: "4", optionName: "B" },
        { menu: "5", optionName: "B" }
      ],

      optionData: [{ optionName: "A" }, { optionName: "B" }]
    };
  }
  render() {
    <div>
      <Parent optionData={optionData} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Here is code for parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <Child optionData={this.props.optionData} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Next is child component:

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      options: this.props.optionData
    });
  }

  deleteOptionA = () => {
    let { options } = this.state;
    newOption = options.filter(option => option.optionName !== "A");
    this.setState({ options: newOption });
  };

  render() {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.deleteOptionA}>deleteOptionA</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I need to remove optionA. However, optionA is also in the state of grandparent component. What is the most efficient way to inform grandparent to remove optionA in menuData and optionData state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the deleteOption handler in the GrandParent and pass the handler to Child. When the delete button is clicked you call the handler passed in the props to remove the option from the state of the parent.

```
     class GrandParent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          menuData: [
            { menu: "1", optionName: "A" },
            { menu: "2", optionName: "A" },
            { menu: "3", optionName: "B" },
            { menu: "4", optionName: "B" },
            { menu: "5", optionName: "B" }
          ],

          optionData: [{ optionName: "A" }, { optionName: "B" }]
        };
      }

      deleteOptionA = () => {
        let { options } = this.state;
         newOption = options.filter(option => option.optionName !== "A");
        this.setState({ options: newOption });
      };

      render() {
        <div>
          <Parent optionData={optionData} deleteOptionA={this.deleteOptionA}/>
        </div>;
      }
    }
```

In Child:

```
  class Child extends Component {    

  render() {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.props.deleteOptionA}>deleteOptionA</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

You do not need to manage state in child component now when the state of the GrandParent change the child will rerender with the new props.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `optionData` itself pass a function from `GrandParant` that removes this option from `GrandParant`'s `state`. Or pass both if `Child` will need to render or use `optionData`.

```
class GrandParent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuData: [
        { menu: "1", optionName: "A" },
        { menu: "2", optionName: "A" },
        { menu: "3", optionName: "B" },
        { menu: "4", optionName: "B" },
        { menu: "5", optionName: "B" }
      ],

      optionData: [{ optionName: "A" }, { optionName: "B" }]
    };
  }

  deleteOptionA () {
    // delete optionA here from optionData and menuData
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Parent deleteOptionA={deleteOptionA} />
    </div>;
  }
}


class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <Child deleteOptionA={this.props.deleteOptionA} />
    </div>;
  }
}

const Child = ({ deleteOptionA }) = (
    <div>
      <button onClick={deleteOptionA}>deleteOptionA</button>
    </div>
);
```

Now you will not need to duplicate the state in 2 different places and `Child` component becomes much simplier.